# Extract an array of variables from an array of structs

Tags: c

Let's say I define a struct as

```
typedef struct worker{
  char name[20];
  int age;
} worker
```

and then I create an array of lenght 20 of such structures,

```
worker *business;
business = malloc(20 * sizeof(worker));
```

Is there any "natural" (i.e. already implemented in the language) way to obtain, from such array, the sub-array of the "age" element?

I'm thinking of something along the lines of

```
business.age
```

where `business.age` is the array of integers of the age of each element of `business`?

Comment: As far as I know - there is no such thing in the language. You have to implement it yourself (allocate a new array of `int`s and populate it).

Comment: C generally doesn't lend itself to abstractions like this. C++20 provides a lot of things for this, however. In particular, you can do `workers | std::views::transform(get_age_in_years)` and get a lazy view of the ages. That pipe is a lot like a pipe on the command line: https://godbolt.org/z/qEEKbGfz7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `age` fields of structs in your array do not form a continuous area of memory. The layout in memory is similar to this:

```
              business[0]                          business[1]
[ 20 bytes of name | 4 bytes of age ][ 20 bytes of name | 4 bytes of age][ 20...
```

Your ages are separated by the name arrays. Since Arrays in C have to be continuous areas of memory without gaps, it is not possible to just refer to an "array" of ages. You can, however, iterate over the ages easily with a for loop or write a function/define a macro to access the age at certain index:

```c
int get_age_at_index(worker* arr, int idx) {
    return arr[idx].age;
}
// OR
#define GET_AGE_AT_INDEX(arr, idx) (arr[idx].age)
```

This could potentially allow for similar semantics to accessing an element of array, if that is what you are after:

```c
int my_age = get_age_at_index(business, 5);
// OR
int my_other_age = GET_AGE_AT_INDEX(business, 3);
```

If you are ok with copying data, you may just allocate an array for 20 ints and copy age from each struct:

```c
int ages[20] = { 0 };
for(int i; i < 20; i++) {
    ages[i] = business[i].age;
}
```

**EDIT**
By doing some *hacky* pointer arithmetic you could get pretty close to semantics of an array access for your ages. I do not recommend actually using it though as it probably is not optimal for the CPU and is less clean than previous solutions. I wanna show it here just as a peculiarity.

When you have a pointer to the beginning of an array in C, like `worker* business` and you index into it like an array
`business[index]` what happens underneath is that the pointer "slides" across the array by an offset. Each element takes `sizeof(worker)` memory in the array, so "sliding" to the next element means "increasing" the pointer by `sizeof(worker)`. In the end, `business[index]` means "Calculate the value `business + index * sizeof(worker)` and access the value at that address as if it was a structure `worker`":

```
business points to the beginning of array:
[ worker struct 0    ][ worker struct 1    ][ worker struct 2    ]
^                     ^                     ^
  0 * sizeof(worker)    1 * sizeof(worker)    2 * sizeof(worker) <-- offsets from the beginning of array
```

If we make the pointer equal to the address of the `age` member in memory of first structure, but cast it to a `worker*`:

```
worker* my_hacky_pointer = (worker*) &(business[0].age);
```

Increasing it by 1 will actually move it by `sizeof(worker)` as this is the type of the pointer. thus, it will move to the `age` member of the next element of the array. If we then cast this pointer back to an `int` and dereference it `*(int*) (my_hacky_pointer + 1)` we will get the value of the `age` field at index 1.

Full example source:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct worker{
  char name[20];
  int age;
} worker;

int main() {
        worker* business = malloc(20 * sizeof(worker));

        business[0].age = 5;
        business[1].age = 6;
        business[2].age = 99;
        business[3].age = 66;
        business[4].age = 78;

        worker* my_hacky_pointer = (worker*) &(business[0].age);
        printf("my age: %d\n", *(int*) (my_hacky_pointer + 0)); // this prints 5
        printf("my age: %d\n", *(int*) (my_hacky_pointer + 1)); // this prints 6
        printf("my age: %d\n", *(int*) (my_hacky_pointer + 2)); // this prints 99
        printf("my age: %d\n", *(int*) (my_hacky_pointer + 3)); // this prints 66
        printf("my age: %d\n", *(int*) (my_hacky_pointer + 4)); // this prints 78
}
```

I advise against using it anywhere, there are better ways to get the same results which are cleaner and easier on the CPU, but thought someone would find it interesting what one can achieve with pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct worker{
char name[20];
int age;
} worker

worker* business;
business = malloc(20 * sizeof(worker));
```

When you allocate an array of struct like above, the memory for `age` is not continuous, you can't access it like an element in a struct.

```
/* error, business is an array */
business->age;
```

If you want continous memory, you have to use one array for `age` and one for `name` instead of a struct.

```
char** name = malloc(20 * 20 * sizeof(char));
int* age = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
```